# Gnome terminal Edit preference run command clear terminal never opens

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I wrote clear command on the **reset and run command** option **Edit**-->**Preference**-->command (something I do not remember) 
After this the terminal never opens when I try opening the command prompt.
Do not know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not remember exactly what you changed, then probably the simplest solution is to reset everything under the `/org/gnome/terminal/` schema.

In the absence of a working `gnome-terminal`, you will need to use an alternate terminal (such as `xterm`) if one is installed, or the Command Runner which should be accessible via keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Then type

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @steeldriver answer you could set `use-custom-command` to `false` (instead of reset all gnome settings). Adapt the profile UID before run the command below.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/use-custom-command false
```

If you have multiple profiles and you don't know which one to select, read the `custom-command` value for each of them.

```
dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/custom-command
```